# How to create a custom cast in Postgres for a complex type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have the following TYPE I have created:

```
CREATE TYPE Person AS (
  first varchar,
  last varchar
);
```

And I can create a literal with:

```
SELECT (PERSON '(Bob, Jones)').first;
-- 'Bob'
```

Now I would like to create a cast that can take a string in the form of `"first last"` and convert it to a person, for example allowing:

```
SELECT 'Bob Jones'::Person
```

And it to return a `Person` object with that. So far I have the following function to do a cast but I am having a hard time with all the quoting. What would be the correct way to write this?

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION makePerson(fullName varchar) RETURNS Person AS $$
     SELECT PERSON '(
                first := SPLIT_PART($1, ' ', 1),
                last  := SPLIT_PART($1, ' ', 2)
               )'
$$ LANGUAGE SQL;

CREATE CAST (varchar AS person) 
       WITH FUNCTION makePerson(varchar) AS ASSIGNMENT;
```

Also, how would you write the following in a function to escape quotes?

```
PERSON '($1, $1)'
```

---

**Update**: it seems I am getting closer. Here is what I have thus far:

```
-- OK
CREATE TYPE Person AS (
  first varchar,
  last varchar
);

-- OK
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION makePerson(fullName varchar) RETURNS Person AS $$
    SELECT SPLIT_PART($1, ' ', 1), SPLIT_PART($1, ' ', 2)
$$ LANGUAGE SQL

-- OK
SELECT makePerson('bob jones');
# "makeperson" (person)
# "(bob,jones)"

-- FAIL
CREATE CAST (varchar AS person) WITH FUNCTION makePerson;
SELECT CAST('Bob Jones' AS Person);

ERROR:  malformed record literal: "Bob Jones"
LINE 11: SELECT CAST('Bob Jones' AS Person)
                     ^
DETAIL:  Missing left parenthesis.
```

Comment: You seem to stick `SQL` in wrong place. `SQL` is not for what you describe in the post. Yes, it is actually possible to do that, but why a person need this?

Comment: @user14063792468 this is a basic (academic) example so that I can test this myself and create actually useful casts afterwards. What's the specific error you notice?

Comment: It is somewhat interesting. What usefulness can be done with those casts? Give an example please. I do not see academic here. By definition.

Answer (score 1):

Postgres can not do implicit conversion of TYPE CAST

```
SELECT 'bob jones'::Person;
```

get the same error as you posted

so you must do

```
 SELECT CAST (makePerson('nbk lives') as Person)
```

Which makews the CAST superfluous

see [example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=351a4635cd52db35d3b4498c233bd9cb)

Comment: thank you so much for this answer. So then is casting to a custom type basically useless in Postgres, or is it used at all?

Comment: it is the **same** syntax only written differently.

Comment: right but it's already of Person type so what's the use of a CAST in the above? `CAST (makePerson('nbk lives') as Person) ` == `makePerson('nbk lives')`. There's no way to do a cast to an explicit type from not-that-type?